# Is that possible to take 3 photos with different exposure compensation on Android?

Tags: android, camera

Below is my code:

```
private void takeMultiPictures(final int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        ToastUtils.show("Capture Successfully!");
        saveMultiPictures();
        return;
    }
    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    int mic = params.getMinExposureCompensation();
    int mac = params.getMaxExposureCompensation();
    switch (n) {
    case 3:
        params.setExposureCompensation(mac);
        break;
    case 2:
        params.setExposureCompensation(mic);
        break;
    case 1:
        params.setExposureCompensation(0);
        break;
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mMultiPictures.add(data);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            takeMultiPictures(n - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

By this code, the camera will take 3 pictures, but the results are not stable.

The First Photo
[image: First photo]

The Second Photo
[image: Second photo]

The Thrid Photo
[image: Third photo]

My device is Galaxy Nexus, the exposure compensation values supported are from -2 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the return values of

```
int mic = params.getMinExposureCompensation();
int mac = params.getMaxExposureCompensation();
```

Are they actually -2 and 2?

you could call

```
mCamera.getParameters(params);
```

after setting the parameters to check if your setting holds.

Comment: I have checked the values. Finally I found on some devices, the exposure compensation change would take about 500 ms to take effect.